# shell scripting validating a single awk variable

Tags: shell, awk

```
{gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", $4); length($4) < 9 || length($4) > 12 } {print $4$1} {print length($4)} { fails4++ }
```

so I have this portion above that supposed to validate the 4th field thus($4) for if lenght < 9 or if lenght is greater than 11 characters its supposed to fail the validation... even after i print the length i get 11 characters and I set validation to greater than 12 but its still failing

What I am trying to DO is correctly account for the length of the field, if there are any white spaces in $4 field it supposed to trim and get the length and fail if its less that 9 or greater 11 characters

```
length($4) < 9 || length($4) > 11 {print $4$1} {print length($4)} { fails4++ }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
{gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/, "", $4); lgth=length($4)} lgth < 9 || lgth > 11{print $4 $1, lgth; fails4++}
```

If not, post some sample input and expected output.

Comment: IT is exactly what i needed thank you! if you could expand on the gsub briefly for other readers it would be great

Comment: The gsub() just removes any white space from the front or back of a string.